# micrometer prometheus : add custom host metrics?

Tags: spring-micrometer, prometheus-java

I am using micrometer and prometheus into a spring boot 2 application : everything works like a charm.
However i recently had an 'infra issue': my application generated 'too many open files'

The prometheus endpoint returns the process_open_files (the files opened by my spring application) and the process_files_max_files which is the max open files allowed by the user running my app.

=> the needed info is : how many files are opened right now for the current linux user.

Has anyone managed to implement this kind of 'lsof' thing and add it to his prometheus micrometer endpoint?

Regards,
Guillaume